# On what level is touch screen support implemented in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touch-screen

I'm trying to use a Linux OS on my tablet PC (`Lenovo Thinkpad Helix 15`). I tried `Ubuntu`, but except for switching and moving windows and bringing up the launcher, there doesn't seem to be a lot of support out of the box.

`Firefox` didn't support scrolling with 2 fingers for example, but I heard `Chromium` does with a certain flag.

I also read, that Ubuntu is working on a tablet version of their OS.

So my question is, on what level would multitouch capabilities be implemented? In the kernel already? The Desktop Environment? The Application Level?

Comment: Multiple levels. Touchscreen driver in the kernel, X server support for the input source and DE/WM/application support for the events. The kernel support is there -- look at any Android tablet or phone.